# Use parents child method in other child class (same parent)

Tags: php, class, oop

I have some issues with OOP. I just started OOP in php and i have some issues.
So i have a question for you, maybe you'll help me.

I have multiple classes (in this case 3)

```
        <?php
            //FILE class.NB.php
            class NB { //databse manipulations, curls
                public $db;
                function __construct($db) {
                    $this->db = $db;
                }

                public function LoginNB () {
                    //something here
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE logins SET login_time = %u", time());
                }
            }

            //FILE class.fn.php
            class FN extends NB {
                public function deposits () {
                    $this->LoginNB();
                    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM deposits");
                }


                public function getUserWihdrawsCompared() {
                    // AND HERE I WOULD LIKE TO USE the DR's ::usersWithdraws
                    $users = $this->usersWithdraws();
                }
            }


            //FILE class.dr.php
            class DR extends NB {
                public function withdraws () {
                    $this->LoginNB();
                    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM withdraws");
                }

                public function usersWithdraws() {
                    $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user_withdraws");
                    /*code here*/
                    return $final_array;
                }

                public function compare_withdraws_deposits () {
                    // AND HERE I WOULD LIKE TO USE the FN's ::deposits
                    $deposit_list = $this->deposits();

                    /* code here */

                    return $final_array;
                }
            }

        ?>
```

So my question is, how is possible to use everything in everywhere.
I saw something with traits but i'm not sure, how to use and what exactly to use.
My problems is what i want to user parent's child method in other child with same parent.
But in the end, i would like to use only the parent class for "runing" implementing in other classes if it's possible.
Like:

```
    $NB = new NB($db);
    $result = $NB->ShowResults();
```

Problem: ShowResults() should use both child's methods and child methods used in  ShowResults() some times use methods from other child class.

Maybe it's impossible but i would appreciate if you could help me. (even with a confirmation that is not possible)

Thank you.

Comment: why you do not organize your code more better? a method to be used in a multiple children should be defined in the parent class.

Comment: @hassan i'm totally agree with you, but i want to use child's method in parent class

Comment: sounds like you want to let the `parent` inherits his `child` which is not valid, if you want to do that, you will need to use an instance of the child it self rather than the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't fully grasped what we mean by "parent" and "child" in OOP, and why they're useful. The purpose of inheritance is not to grant access to the methods of one class in another, or to automatically run multiple implementations of the same thing. Instead, the purpose is to allow code *outside* the classes to call *one* of the implementations without needing to know *which one*.

So, if I have an instance of class `NB`, I know I can call `LoginNB` on it. If what I'm passed is actually an instance of class `FN`, *that will still work*; class `FN` will either inherit that method, or reimplement it a different way, but with the same external signature.

However, class `NB` doesn't know anything about what classes inherit from it, any more than a function knows where else it is called from; the relationship only goes one way.